# How to propagate parent attributes in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to propagate child attributes in parent class without having to access it by its related name? Please consider the following example:

```
class BaseA(models.Model):
    pass

class BaseB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('BaseA')

class A(BaseA):
    base = models.OneToOneField('BaseA', related_name='related')
    field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def some_method(self):
        pass

class B(BaseB):
    base = models.OneToOneField('BaseB')

# code in view
model_b = B()
model_b.a.some_method()
```

I cannot access the **some_method** method because **model_b.a** returns a **BaseA()** instance instead of **A()**, if I want to access this method I have to:

```
model_b.a.related.some_method()
# or
model_b.a.related.field
```

Is there a way to propagate the properties and methods from the base class so I won't have to access using the related name?

Comment: Well, inheritence doesn't work backwards! If you want `BaseA` to have `some_method`, you have to implement it in `BaseA` and `A` will have it automatically. Why do you want it the other way round.

Comment: Because the method is specific of class A. If I create a class C that inherits from BaseA I don't want C to access the A methods and properties.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be both inheriting from BaseA and adding a OneToOnefield to it in the model - those are separate relationships but do the same thing. Choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this to `BaseA` as a util:

```
class BaseA(models.Model):
    def some_method(self):
        return self.related.some_method()
```

If this is called for an non-`A` `BaseA`, it will raise an `AttributeError` which is plausible enough. If you want propagate all methods, you can override `__getattr__`. This will only look at `self.related` if the attribute isn't found on the `BaseA` instance itself:

```
class BaseA(models.Model):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.related, item)
```

But adding attributes dynamically like this should be a last resort, one that makes code navigation and debugging harder, and renders other IDE features like code completion unusable. IMO, it is preferable to put all the methods you might actually want to call on `BaseA` instances in the class explicitly.